# How to Load and save image using node.js?

Tags: node.js

A have this code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var data;
var options = {
  host: 'nodejs.org',
  port: 80,
  path: '/images/logo.png',
  method: 'GET'
};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    data += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function () {
    fs.writeFile('1.png', data, function (err) {
      if(err) 
        console.log('NNOOOOOOOOOOOO');
    });
  });
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('error: ' + e.message);
});
req.end();
```

This script create file 1.png and save got data but I can't open it in Windows.

Please, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream('1.png');
  res.pipe(file);
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('error: ' + e.message);
});
req.end();
```

#### Update

I checked your code and found two things :

1. The `data` is not properly initialised.
2. Use setEncoding to treat response as binary. Don't need to specify encoding in `writeFile`

So just add these two lines in beginning of `http.request` callback :

```
  res.setEncoding("binary") ;
  var data='';
```

Then your code should work fine.

Comment: @Sable Added the explanation

Comment: Just saying - after fixing the code with this solution - the file doesn't open because nodejs.org/images/logo.png returning "301 Moved Permanently" and saving the headers into the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the proper encoding.

```
res.setEncoding('binary')


fs.writeFile('1.png', data, {encoding: 'binary'}, function(err){
```

Comment: Windows still can't open this file.

Comment: I can't test this at the moment, which is why there was a small bug in the code I supplied. The writeFile takes an object as an option and not just a string. Still can't test this, but that might be the issue.

Comment: any update on this? what and how to provide the encoding for saving image?